# How to echo a text in a jquery val(val)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a jquery code :

```
(function($) {
$.fn.countdown = function(options) {
    var settings = { 'date': null };
    if(options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
    }

    this_sel = $(this);

    function count_exec() {
        eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;    // Parse the date string
        currentDate =   Math.floor($.now() / 1000);                 // Find the timestamp for now
        seconds = eventDate - currentDate;                  // Find the number of seconds remaining

        days =          Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));       // Divide to find the number of days remaining
        seconds -=      days * 60 * 60 * 24;                        // Subtract the number of (complete, => 24 hours) days calculated above

        hours =         Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));            // Get the number of hours from that modified number ^
        seconds -=      hours * 60 * 60;

        minutes =       Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        seconds -=      minutes * 60;

        this_sel.find('#days').val(days).trigger('change');
        this_sel.find('#hours').val(hours).trigger('change');
        this_sel.find('#mins').val(minutes).trigger('change');
        this_sel.find('#secs').val(seconds).trigger('change');

    } // End of count_exec();

    count_exec();

    interval = setInterval(count_exec, 1000);

} 
// End of the main function
}) (jQuery);
```

and there is a html markup here :

```
<input class="knob" id="days">
<input class="knob" id="hours">
<input class="knob" id="mins">
<input class="knob" id="secs">
```

I want to add text after every element output .
for example , after the days input i want to place "Remaining Days" . how can i do that ?
i think i should edit these lines :

```
            seconds = eventDate - currentDate;                  // Find the number of seconds remaining

        days =          Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));       // Divide to find the number of days remaining
        seconds -=      days * 60 * 60 * 24;                        // Subtract the number of (complete, => 24 hours) days calculated above

        hours =         Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));            // Get the number of hours from that modified number ^
        seconds -=      hours * 60 * 60;

        minutes =       Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        seconds -=      minutes * 60;
```

please see these pictures to understand what i'm asking ...
what the code shows now :

[image: http://uploadtak.com/images/j91_Untitled1.jpg]

[image: http://uploadtak.com/images/j91_Untitled1.jpg]

What i want to be shown:

[image: http://uploadtak.com/images/v8243_Untitled2.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) function.

```
this_sel.find('#days').val(days).after('<span>Remaining Days</span>').trigger('change');
```

or

```
$('<span>Remaining Days</span>').insertAfter(this_sel.find('#days'));
```

**UPDATE:**

Because of source code is invoked in interval, [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) is not usable for this case.

Better solution is change the HTML and use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead. New HTML:

```
<input class="knob" id="days"><span></span>
<input class="knob" id="hours"><span></span>
<input class="knob" id="mins"><span></span>
<input class="knob" id="secs"><span></span>
```

New jQuery to set the text after:

```
this_sel.find('#days').val(days).trigger('change').next().text('Remaining Days');
```

Comment: i've tried your code . but there is a problem , "Remaining Days" adds to the screen again and again every second ...

Comment: ough, i see... Change `<input class="knob" id="...">` to `<input class="knob" id="..."><span></span>` (add empty span after each input). And use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `after()`. Then you get `this_sel.find('#days').val(days).trigger('change').next().text('Remaining Days');`. I move `trigger()` invocation also, because `next()` changes your jQuery object which you're working with in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i undertood your question at all...

I would do something like this.

After get with all your functions the time remaining (that you already have) you get that in a return var, for example **time**

so, you can create other var like this

var text = "days"

and print something like this `$("myresult).val(time+"<br />"+text);`

Comment: tried this . but output is "NaN"

Comment: its NaN maybe cause one of your variables its undefined

Comment: Putting `<br />` into `input`, really?